# Print even numbers n number of times, using while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

#### Task

Write a Python script which reads a positive integer `n` from standard input and outputs the first `n` even natural numbers, one per line.

(Take the natural numbers to be 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on.)

I'm a beginner to Python, so I need to use a `while` loop, without `for` or `in`.

We learned:

```
while i < n:
   print i
   i = i + 1
```

So need a variation of that for this answer.

Comment: `n = int(input())`.  Good luck!

Comment: Why can't Python beginners use `for` loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print 2 times i for each i.

```
n = int(input())

i = 1
while i <= n:
   print(2*i)
   i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Hi, this code should work!

```
    n = int(input("Input a number: ")) #Taking in user input to use as n
    
    i = 2 #starting with the first even natural number, which will always be 2

    while i <= n:#while loop will continue until we reach user-inputted n times
        print(i) #will print i (which will be always be 2 for the first round)
        i += 2 #bc you only want even natural numbers, will add 2 to each iteration for even
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also determine the number is even or odd by % inside the loop

```
#take the input
n = int(input())
#start the loop
i = 1
while i <= n:
   #this condition mean the i is divisable by 2 (is even)
   if i % 2 == 0:
      print(i)
   i = i + 1
```

this code will print even number only

Answer (score -1):

```
n = int(input("enter any number :"))
i = 2 
While i <= n:
    print(i)
    i += 2
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?